# Is it possible to call an overridden method outside the main class?

Tags: java

```
public class OverrideAnimals {

    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("animal sounds!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        OverrideAnimals animals=new OverrideAnimals ();
        OverrideAnimals dog=new PolyDog();
   }
}

class PolyDog extends OverrideAnimals {

    @Override
    public void makeSound(){
         System.out.println("arf!!! arf!!! arf!!!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The class that overrides can, however, call "super".

```
class PolyDog extends OverrideAnimals {
    public void superMakeSound() {
        super.makeSound();
     }

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        // ..
```